# Using Android setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true) and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I'm using a custom view for my actionbar and a viewpager with for fragments in the adapter. When I first load the activity, everything is perfect. Until I start swiping through the pageview then another layer of the actionbar appears below it. Check the before and after images below

- Before swipe (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ecDe2_CjMxalBILTB4UVJxdW8/view?usp=sharing)
- Swipe to the next fragment (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ecDe2_CjMxb2diR2YyZ3VCUUU/view?usp=sharing) the unwanted layer has appeared :/

-

**Source**

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gray"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/camera"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

HomeActivity.java onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

ActionBar action_bar = getActionBar();
homepage_adapter = new HomePageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

View custom_view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tabs, null);

pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(homepage_adapter);
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

action_bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
action_bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

action_bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
action_bar.setCustomView(custom_view);
```

I tried reming the OnPageChangeListener suspecting it might be causing the issue but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using an ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity